# Work with Contacts in Apex when enabled Person Accounts

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to work with contacts in a salesforce org, where Person Accounts are enabled. Apparently, you can not query contacts anymore. A simple query  like:

```
List<Contact> cs = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact];
```

fails, because of:

```
Line: 1, Column: 15
Illegal assignment from List<Contact> to List<Contact>
```

Obviously

```
List<Contact> cs = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact WHERE IsPersonAccount = false];
```

also fails (same error). The query works as expected with the Query Editor, though. To make things even worse, when loading the records in `List<sObject> sobjs`, I can not cast them later into contacts.

```
for (sObject obj : sObjs)
    System.debug(obj.getSObjectType());
```

returns "Contact", but

```
Contact c = (Contact) obj;
```

just throws `Incompatible types since an instance of SObject is never an instance of Contact`. Needless to say, that I can not access any fields, and the code works perfectly when querying other sObjects such as leads.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can execute

```
List<Contact> cs = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact];
```

In an org with person accounts.

Often the explanation for weird compiler errors like this is having created an Apex Class of your own called `Contact`. Then the list on the left-hand-side ends up referring to your class, and the right-hand-side is the sObject. It also happens pretty often if someone creates a class called `Test`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured that out by myself literally seconds before I read your response :).