# How to access ordinary Contact fields when PersonAccount is enabled

Tags: apex, person-accounts

In my org, we have enabled PersonAccount.

Now it seems like we can no longer create an ordinary Contact.

this simple code

```
Contact test = new Contact();
test.email = 'test@mail.com';

system.debug(test);
```

is throwing this kind of error 
 [image]

is there any way to create a 'standard' contact like we normally could like when personAccount hadn't been enabled ?

Comment: An org with person accounts enabled still has the ability to use the normal Contact object and its fields... your error is most likely because you named your variable `test` which is a system class name too. Change `test` to some other name and try again. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/209183/660

Answer (score 0):

PersonAccounts are pretty tricky to manage.  I'm listing the [Considerations for PersonAccounts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_behavior.htm&type=5) article for your info - although it doesn't directly help you with this question, it should help you understand what changes are made when PersonAccounts is enabled on SF.

Go to the Contacts object in Setup directly, and see what fields are listed on the object, and also check Accounts and PersonAccounts, which is its own object.  The PA object is supposed to be a combination of Account and Contact fields.

I'm responding from memory - I don't have immediate access to a PA org, but I remember the mission it was to reconcile all the Account/Contact structures and connections when I did.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got it. It's because I was creating an `Apex Class` with the name `Contact`. The compiler thought I was instantiating the custom `Contact` class instead of the `SObject`.